# Change Text in multilingual Magento 1 Store

Tags: magento-1.9, footer-links, multi-language

How can I change footer links after language shifting in a multilingual Magento 1 Store ?

I am trying to follow this links

https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001957893-How-to-translate-footer-content-different-language-storeview

[image]

Comment: I don't know how outputting footer links in weltpixel theme, but, in default Magento 1 theme for this purpose, you should create separate blocks (with the same identifier) and assign them to proper store views. Example: https://prnt.sc/nemwx7 (in my example identifier for blocks is "footer_links_sm" but in your case, it can be either)

Comment: Thanks @PetroChaikivskyi. I did same like you but I can't see change in front end. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFPou.png

Comment: Please ensure that content on your page is not cached, you are editing right cms block and check changed on right store view.

Comment: Thanks @PetroChaikivskyi, I disabled my cache. https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0HwV.png . But I cann't see footer links when I switch Language.

Comment: I can't give you an answer without investigation weltpixel theme working, sorry, but the decision always works form me.

Comment: Thanks @PetroChaikivskyi. I am not using `weltpixel theme`. I am using `Fastest` theme. Thanks.